# zurb foundation icon fonts in a Slim template link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, zurb-foundation, slim-lang

I am using a slim template file for a Rails form. I'd like to use a Foundation icon-font as the graphic in the link, but cannot seem to find a way to include the font in the link_to. Here is the code in question.

```
h3 Categories

table
  tr
    th <span class="secondary radius label">Category Name</span>
    th colspan="2" <span class="secondary radius label">Actions</span> 
  - for category in @categories do
    tr 
      td #{category.name}
      td #{link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category)} <i class="general foundicon-edit">
```

In the last line, I can get the icon to display next to the link (as shown), but I can't see how to embed it in the link title itself (currently set to 'Edit').

Any help greatly appreciated!

fyi:: Rails 3.2.11, Ruby 1.9.3, Foundation 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but this should get you close:

```
td
  = link_to edit_category_path(category) do
      Edit <i class="general foundicon-edit"></i>
```

This might work too:

```
td #{link_to 'Edit <i class="general foundicon-edit"></i>'.html_safe, edit_category_path(category)}
```

Comment: The second option worked fine, thanks! The first one didn't, but I am going to play a bit with it yet, as it feels like a better final answer ;-)